# SQL Server error 515

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `SINVOICE` and another table called `SINVOICE_LINE`.

I need to put all columns of `SINVOICE` into `SINVOICE`_LINE.

I have created the corresponding columns and was trying to copy the values. The primary key of `SINVOICE` is `SINVOICE_CODE`, while the primary key for `SINVOICE_LINE` is a composite key `(SINVOICE_CODE, SINVOICE_LINE_NUMBER)`.

I wrote the following query:

```
INSERT INTO SINVOICE_LINE (sinvoice.ITINERARY_CODE) 
   SELECT sinvoice_line.ITINERARY_CODE 
   FROM SINVOICE 
   INNER JOIN sinvoice_line ON sinvoice.sinvoice_code = sinvoice_line.sinvoice_code;
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column SINVOICE_CODE, table SINVOICE_LINE; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I do not understand why I'm getting this error as I am not trying to insert any value in `SINVOICE_CODE` column.

Thanks!!!

Comment: "Hey guys I'm not inserting any value into SINVOICE_CODE and it says I can't insert empty values" Can you really not figure this one out on your own?

Comment: Please try formatting the TSQL in your question. It's really quite unreadable as it stands.

Comment: I'm not isnerting any value beacause I already have values in that column...

Comment: You're `INSERT`ing a new row. You can't already have a value in that column, in the absence of a default constraint.

Comment: so how do I tell it that I want the corresponding values inserted into the right row (check each sinvoice.sinvoice_code and sinvoice_line.sinvoice_code and insert the corresponding value of itinerary_code where they're equal). I apologize I have worked only a few times with SQL SERVER this is just a stage of my project and I am not really used to queries! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need UPDATE instead of INSERT here.

Try that:

```
UPDATE  SINVOICE_LINE
SET ITINERARY_CODE = sinvoice.ITINERARY_CODE
from SINVOICE 
WHERE sinvoice.sinvoice_code = sinvoice_line.sinvoice_code;
```